# How to run pynput and FFMPEG script using CRONTAB?

Tags: scripts, cron, python3, ffmpeg

I need to start **three python3 scripts and a shell script using crontab**. These scripts should run at the same time without any delay. Each script runs exactly for one minute. For instance, I have scheduled crontab to run these scripts every 5 minutes.

My problem is that, if I attempt to run each script individually from **terminal** it executes with no further errors, but using crontab nothing happens.

**Here's my crontab set up:**

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/user/Desktop/ && /usr/bin/python3 script1.py >> report1.log

*/5 * * * * cd /home/user/Desktop/ && /usr/bin/python3 script2.py >> report2.log

*/5 * * * * cd /home/user/Desktop/ && /usr/bin/python3 script3.py >> report3.log

*/5 * * * * cd /home/user/Desktop/ && /usr/bin/sh script4.sh >> report4.log
```

***In addition I need to mention that the shell script contains this command (FFMPEG):***

```
#!/bin/bash

parent_dir=`dirname \`pwd\`` 
folder_name="/Data/Webcam" 
new_path=$parent_dir$folder_name  


if [ -d "$new_path" ]; then
    echo "video_audio folder exists..."
else
    echo "Creating video_audio folder in the current directory..."
    mkdir -p -- "$new_path"
    sudo chmod 777 "$new_path"
    echo "Folder created"
    echo
fi

now=$(date +%F) 
now="$( echo -e "$now" | tr  '-' '_'  )"
sub_dir=$new_path'/'$now 

if [ -d "$sub_dir" ]; then
    echo "Date Sub-directory exists..."
    echo
else
    echo "Error: ${sub_dir} not found..."
    echo "Creating date sub-directory..."
    mkdir -p -- "$sub_dir"
    sudo chmod 777 "$sub_dir"
    echo "Date sub-directory created..."
    echo
fi

fname=$(date +%H_%M_%S)".avi"
video_dir=$sub_dir'/'$fname
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 1 -i default -f v4l2 -i  /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -t 00:01:00 $video_dir
```

**The log file of that script contains the following:**

```
video_audio folder exists...
Date Sub-directory exists...

Package ffmpeg is already installed...
Package v4l-utils is already installed...

Package: ffmpeg
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: video
Installed-Size: 2010
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Replaces: libav-tools (<< 6:12~~), qt-faststart (<< 7:2.7.1-3~)
Depends: libavcodec58 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libavdevice58 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libavfilter7 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libavformat58 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libavresample4 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libavutil56 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libc6 (>= 2.29), libpostproc55 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.10), libswresample3 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1), libswscale5 (= 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1)
Suggests: ffmpeg-doc
Breaks: libav-tools (<< 6:12~~), qt-faststart (<< 7:2.7.1-3~), winff (<< 1.5.5-5~)
Description: Tools for transcoding, streaming and playing of multimedia files
 FFmpeg is the leading multimedia framework, able to decode, encode, transcode,
 mux, demux, stream, filter and play pretty much anything that humans and
 machines have created. It supports the most obscure ancient formats up to the
 cutting edge.
 .
 This package contains:
  * ffmpeg: a command line tool to convert multimedia files between formats
  * ffplay: a simple media player based on SDL and the FFmpeg libraries
  * ffprobe: a simple multimedia stream analyzer
  * qt-faststart: a utility to rearrange Quicktime files
Homepage: https://ffmpeg.org/
Original-Maintainer: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <debian-multimedia@lists.debian.org>
Package: v4l-utils
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 2104
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.18.0-2build1
Replaces: ivtv-utils (<< 1.4.1-2), media-ctl
Depends: libv4l-0 (= 1.18.0-2build1), libv4l2rds0 (= 1.18.0-2build1), libc6 (>= 2.17), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libudev1 (>= 183)
Breaks: ivtv-utils (<< 1.4.1-2), media-ctl
Description: Collection of command line video4linux utilities
 v4l-utils contains the following video4linux command line utilities:
 .
  decode_tm6000: decodes tm6000 proprietary format streams
  rds-ctl: tool to receive and decode Radio Data System (RDS) streams
  v4l2-compliance: tool to test v4l2 API compliance of drivers
  v4l2-ctl, cx18-ctl, ivtv-ctl: tools to control v4l2 controls from the cmdline
  v4l2-dbg: tool to directly get and set registers of v4l2 devices
  v4l2-sysfs-path: sysfs helper tool
Original-Maintainer: Gregor Jasny <gjasny@googlemail.com>
Homepage: https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-utils/
```

**Due to the reason that the python files are of the same structure I'm uploading a sample file here:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Timer
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import logging
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.realpath(__file__)), "../"))

from Functions import utils as ut

if __name__=='__main__':

    ut.initialize_dirs()
    rec_file = ''.join(('mouse_',ut.get_date(),'.txt'))
    raw_data = ut.get_name('Mouse')
    rec_file = os.path.join(raw_data,rec_file)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=rec_file,level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(asctime)s    %(message)s")

    try:
        with Listener(on_move=ut.on_move, on_click=ut.on_click,on_scroll=ut.on_scroll) as listener:
            Timer(60, listener.stop).start()
            listener.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(0)

    print('Exiting logger...')
```

**I'm also uploading the functions that I use:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from serial import Serial
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import collections
import logging
import shutil
import serial
import time
import sys
import os

click_held = False
button = None


def on_move(x,y):
    """The callback to call when mouse move events occur

    Args:
        x (float): The new pointer position
        y (float): The new pointer poisition
    """
    if click_held:
        logging.info("MV    {0:>8}  {1:>8}  {2:>8}:".format(x,y,str(None)))
    else:
        logging.info("MV    {0:>8}  {1:>8}  {2:>8}:".format(x,y,str(None)))


def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    """The callback to call when a mouse button is clicked

    Args:
        x (float): Mouse coordinates on screen
        y (float): Mouse coordinates on screen
        button (str): one of the Button values
        pressed (bool): Pressed is whether the button was pressed
    """
    global click_held
    if pressed:
        click_held = True
        logging.info("CLK    {0:>7}    {1:>6}    {2:>13}".format(x,y,button))
    else:
        click_held = False
        logging.info("RLS    {0:>7}    {1:>6}    {2:>13}".format(x,y,button))


def on_scroll(x,y,dx,dy):
    """The callback to call when mouse scroll events occur

    Args:
        x (float): The new pointer position on screen
        y (float): The new pointer position on screen
        dx (int): The horizontal scroll. The units of scrolling is undefined
        dy (int): The vertical scroll. The units of scrolling is undefined
    """
    if dy == -1:
        logging.info("SCRD    {0:>6}    {1:>6}    {2:>6}".format(x,y,str(None)))
    elif dy == 1:
        logging.info("SCRU    {0:>6}    {1:>6}    {2:>6}".format(x,y,str(None)))
    else:
        pass


def on_press_keys(key):
    """The callback to call when a button is pressed.

    Args:
        key (str): A KeyCode,a Key or None if the key is unknown
    """
    subkeys = [
    'Key.alt','Key.alt_gr','Key.alt_r','Key.backspace',
    'Key.space','Key.ctrl','Key.ctrl_r','Key.down',
    'Key.up','Key.left','Key.right','Key.page_down',
    'Key.page_up','Key.enter','Key.shift','Key.shift_r'
    ]

    key = str(key).strip('\'')
    if(key in subkeys):
        #print(key)
        logging.info(key)
    else:
        pass


def record_chair(output_file):
    """Read the data stream coming from the serial monitor
       in order to get the sensor readings

    Args:
        output_file (str): The file name, where the data stream will be stored
    """
    serial_port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
    baud_rate = 9600
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port,baud_rate)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=output_file,level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(asctime)s    %(message)s")
    flag = False
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < 60.0:
        try:
            serial_data = str(ser.readline().decode().strip('\r\n'))
            time.sleep(0.2)
            tmp = serial_data.split('  ')[0] #Getting Sensor Id
            if(tmp == 'A0'):
                flag = True
            if (flag and tmp != 'A4'):
                #print(serial_data)
                logging.info(serial_data)
            if(flag and tmp == 'A4'):
                flag = False
                #print(serial_data)
                logging.info(serial_data)
        except (UnicodeDecodeError, KeyboardInterrupt) as err:
            print(err)
            print(err.args)
            sys.exit(0)


def initialize_dirs():
    """Create the appropriate directories in order to save
       and process the collected data
    """
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    os.chdir('..')
    current_path = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) #/Multodal_User_Monitoring
    current_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Data')
    create_subdirs([current_path])

    #Create mouse log folder
    mouse = os.path.join(current_path,'Mouse')
    create_subdirs([mouse])
    #Create mouse subfolders
    names = concat_names(mouse)
    create_subdirs(names)

    #Create keyboard log  folder
    keyboard = os.path.join(current_path,'Keyboard')
    create_subdirs([keyboard])
    #Create keyboard subfolders
    names = concat_names(keyboard)
    create_subdirs(names)

    #Create the chair log folder
    chair = os.path.join(current_path,'Chair')
    create_subdirs([chair])
    #Create chair subfolders
    names = concat_names(chair)
    create_subdirs(names)

    #Create webcam log folder
    webcam = os.path.join(current_path,'Webcam')
    create_subdirs([webcam])

def concat_names(dir) -> str:
    """Concatenate the given folder names
       with the appropriate path

    Args:
        dir (str): The directory to create the subfolders

    Returns:
        list: The new absolute paths
    """
    raw_data = os.path.join(dir,'Raw')
    edited_data = os.path.join(dir,'Edited_logs')
    csv_data = os.path.join(dir,'CSV')
    features = os.path.join(dir,'Features')
    dirs = [raw_data,edited_data,csv_data,features]
    return dirs


def create_subdirs(paths):
    """Create sub directories given some absolute paths

    Args:
        paths (list): A list containing the paths to be created
    """
    for index,path in enumerate(paths):
        if(os.path.isdir(paths[index])):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(paths[index])


def round_down(num,divisor) -> int:
    """Round the number of lines contained into the recording file,
       down to the nearest multiple of the given divisor

    Args:
        num (int): The number of lines contained into the given log file
        divisor (int): The divisor in order to get tuples of divisor

    Returns:
        int: The nearest multiple of five
    """
    return num-(num%divisor)


def get_date() -> str:
    """Get the current date in order to properly name
       the recored log files
    Returns:
        str: The current date in: YY_MM_DD format
    """
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')


def get_name(modality) -> str:
    """Save the recorded log into /Data/<Modality_name>/Raw

    Args:
        modality (str): The log data source

    Returns:
        str: The absolute path where each recording is saved
    """
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    current_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Data')

    if modality == 'Chair':
        chair_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality,'Raw')
        return chair_path

    elif modality == 'Mouse':
        mouse_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality,'Raw')
        return mouse_path

    elif modality == 'Keyboard':
        keyboard_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality,'Raw')
        return keyboard_path


def crawl_dir(target,folder) -> str:
    """Enumerate all the given files in a directory
       based on the given file extension

    Args:
        target (str): The file to search for
        folder (str): The folder to search

    Returns:
        [type]: A list containing the file names
    """
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    path = os.path.join(current_path,folder)
    file_names =[]
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if(f.endswith(target)):
            fname=os.path.join(path,f)
            file_names.append(fname)
    return file_names


def convert_keys2_csv(input_file,output_file):
    """Convert the data stream file(keylogger recording) from .txt to .csv format

    Args:
        input_file (str): The data stream file in .txt format
        output_file (str): The csv extension file name
    """
    df = pd.read_fwf(input_file)
    col_names = ['Date','Time','Key']
    df.to_csv(output_file,header=col_names,encoding='utf-8',index=False)


def convert_mouse2_csv(input_file,output_file):
    """Convert the data stream file(mouselogger recording) from .txt to .csv format

    Args:
        input_file (str): The data stream file in .txt format
        output_file (str): The csv extension file name
    """
    df = pd.read_fwf(input_file)
    col_names = ['Date','Time','Action','PosX','PosY','Button']
    df.to_csv(output_file,header=col_names,encoding='utf-8',index=False)


def convert_chair_2_csv(input_file,output_file):
    """Convert the data stream file(chair recording)
       from .txt to .csv format

    Args:
        input_file (str): The data stream file in .txt format
        output_file (str): The csv extension file name
    """
    if(os.path.isfile(input_file)):
        pass
    else:
        print('Invalid working directory...')
        print('Aborting...')
        sys.exit(0)

    tmp0,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4 = 0,1,2,3,4

    line_number = 0
    for line in open(input_file).readlines():
        line_number += 1

    rounded_line = round_down(line_number,5)
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)

    with open(input_file,'r') as f1:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i in range(rounded_line // 5):
            #Sensor:Analog input 0 values
            Sid0 = lines[i+tmp0]
            temp = Sid0.split()
            d['Sid0'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 1 values
            Sid1 = lines[i+tmp1]
            temp = Sid1.split()
            d['Sid1'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 2 values
            Sid2 = lines[i+tmp2]
            temp = Sid2.split()
            d['Sid2'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 3 values
            Sid3 = lines[i+tmp3]
            temp = Sid3.split()
            d['Sid3'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 4 values
            Sid4 = lines[i+tmp4]
            temp = Sid4.split()
            d['Sid4'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])

            tmp0 += 4
            tmp1 += 4
            tmp2 += 4
            tmp3 += 4
            tmp4 += 4

    l = []
    for i in range(rounded_line // 5):
        date = d['Sid0'][i][0]
        time = d['Sid0'][i][1]
        A0_val = d['Sid0'][i][3]
        A1_val = d['Sid1'][i][3]
        A2_val = d['Sid2'][i][3]
        A3_val = d['Sid3'][i][3]
        A4_val = d['Sid4'][i][3]
        l.append([date,time,A0_val,A1_val,A2_val,A3_val,A4_val])

    sensor_readings_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(l)
    sensor_readings_df.columns = ['Date','Time','A0','A1','A2','A3','A4']
    sensor_readings_df.to_csv(output_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    del l


def parse_raw_data(modality):
    """Convert each modality's raw data into csv format and move
       the edited raw data into the appropriate Edited_logs folder

    Args:
        modality (str): The data source
    """
    #Change directories
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) #/Functions
    os.chdir('..')
    current_path = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) #/Multimodal_User_Monitoring
    os.chdir('./Data')#/Multimodal_User_Monitoring/Data
    current_path = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) #/Multimodal_User_Monitoring/Data
    current_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality) #example: /Multimodal_User_Monitoring/Data/<Modality>
    raw_data_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Raw')
    csv_data_path = os.path.join(current_path,'CSV')
    edited_logs_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Edited_logs')

    txt_names = crawl_dir('.txt',raw_data_path)
    csv_names = []
    for elem in txt_names:
        name = elem.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
        csv_name = name+'.csv'
        tmp = os.path.join(csv_data_path,csv_name)
        csv_names.append(tmp)

    if modality == 'Mouse':
        if len(txt_names) == len(csv_names):
            for i, elem in enumerate(txt_names):
            #for i in range(len(txt_names)):
                convert_mouse2_csv(txt_names[i],csv_names[i])
                shutil.move(txt_names[i],edited_logs_path)

    elif modality == 'Keyboard':
        if len(txt_names) == len(csv_names):
            for i, elem in enumerate(txt_names):
            #for i in range(len(txt_names)):
                convert_keys2_csv(txt_names[i],csv_names[i])
                shutil.move(txt_names[i],edited_logs_path)

    elif modality == 'Chair':
        if len(txt_names) == len(csv_names):
            for i, elem in enumerate(txt_names):
            #for i in range(len(txt_names)):
                convert_chair_2_csv(txt_names[i],csv_names[i])
                shutil.move(txt_names[i],edited_logs_path)
```

**I need to mention that the logs of the python3 scripts are empty**

Comment: There are plenty of questions on here like this and I’ve never found a definitive guide about how to diagnose it. Sometimes it’s just paths, sometimes environment variables, and sometimes something else. You may well find it easier to use systemd units and timers. They are well documented and relatively easy to use. https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/

Comment: What is systemd?

Comment: Systemd is at the core of Ubuntu and many other distros. In simple terms it’s the thing that starts up all the processes that make your computer work and it manages a lot of the logging. It includes functionality that allows you to schedule jobs (systemd timers). I suggest you google it or search YouTube. It’s already running on your Ubuntu computer, you just need to add some configuration to get it to run the jobs in your question